# Best way to complete Full Disk Encryption with Lubuntu 22.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, lubuntu, encryption, 22.04

Edit: So I figured everything out, as described in detail here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2476642
The Lubuntu 22.04 installer with the FDE option doesn't use a /boot-partition at all. It needs only one root-partition for everything, which gets encrypted. So just simply using the installer will encrypt the boot-loader second stage file-system and set up a completely encrypted system; without making use of LVM. My install had a small swap file active, but for suspend-to-disk to work, I had to increase the swap file size, add the 'resume'-parameters to the grub config and for the LXQt-GUI-button I had to create a policykit-file.

---

Original questions were:

I'd like to install Lubuntu 22.04 with bootloader etc. encrypted as far as possible, with working suspend-to-disk, to an old netbook's SSD; no EFI, no other OS.

I found this guide for Ubuntu, but I also read that the Lubuntu-installer would handle FDE completely different, is that true?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019

How should the disk be partitioned on a system without EFI?
Would it be reasonable not to use LVM and just have a swap file on the encrypted partition?
Is it still necessary to use LUKS1 instead of LUKS2 to install GRUB2 like the guide says, or is LUKS1 preferable on devices with low RAM anyway?
Is the recommendation to use a keyfile as safe as having to enter the password twice?

Comment: I recommend you use the Ubuntu installer's built in encryption option. Having said that, I am voting to close this question as opinion based.

Comment: Will the Lubuntu-installer encrypt the the boot-loader second stage file-system?

Comment: I have not used Lubuntu with encryption. If my experience with Ubuntu is any indication, then the answer is no.

Comment: I too recommend using the default installer's method; as what you describe you're after (*excluding suspend to disk; only suspend to ram is QA tested for routinely*) is on the [QA testing checklist of Lubuntu](https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/release-team/testing-checklist/) with a number of BIOS tests you'll note (how pre-uEFI is referred in testing).  The default install does not provide a large enough *swapfile* to allow suspend to disk.. so that would need to be increased; or swap partition setup manually (*which is tested for too, but not with encryption*).  Lubuntu uses full-disk encryption

Comment: +1; Thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Comment: I also managed to create encrypted root partition in Lubuntu 22.04.2 installer but only after I manually created EFI partition and LVM PV in the terminal (I installed on LVM) because when I create LVM PV in the installer it simply discards all the manual partitioning after creation of LV for some reason..